# Recursive method for a multilinked structure

Tags: python

I have this class in python which accepts two hash and links them together. What I want is to be able to recursively fetch all linked hashes, however I'm struggling to write a correct recursive function.
What I have so far:

```
class MultiLink:
    def __init__(self):
        self.map = {}

    def get(self, md5: str, scanned: list = None) -> list:
        matches = []
        scanned = scanned or []
        for match in self.map[md5]:
            matches.append(match)

            if match in scanned:
                continue

            scanned.append(match)
            for mmatch in self.map[match]:
                if mmatch not in scanned:
                    matches += self.get(mmatch, scanned=scanned)

        return list(set(matches))

    def link(self, first: str, second: str) -> None:
        try:
            self.map[first].append(second)
        except KeyError:
            self.map[first] = [second]

        try:
            self.map[second].append(first)
        except KeyError:
            self.map[second] = [first]
```

As you can see the output does not perform as I expect it to:

```
l = MultiLink()
l.link("a", "b")
l.link("b", "c")
l.link("c", "a")
l.get("c")
```

This outputs `['c', 'b', 'a']`, but `l.get("a")` outputs `['c', 'b']`.

If I then do `l.link("d", "a")`, it returns `['c', 'a']` instead of the whole set of results.

What I want instead, is for the get function to start at a given node and recursively follow all other nodes until it fetches all directly or indirectly linked nodes. So `l.get("b")` would return `["a", "c", "d"]`, "d" included because it's linked through "a". Likewise `l.get("d")` would get all the other letters because they are linked through "a".

This is my first attempt at writing something like this, so I'm sure I'm making a very stupid error somewhere, but I cannot find it by myself. Does anyone know how to make this work? Or if there's already an implementation of this somewhere? I checked the collections module but I found nothing of interest there.

Comment: What is the expected output from your given samples?

Comment: You need to describe what the behavior is *supposed to be*. It isn't obvious from your description. For example, "accepts two hashes and links them together" isn't using standard terminology, and it isn't clear what you mean

Comment: I would like to basically recursively follow all links. So in my example, l.get("c") would return ["d", "b", "a"], because each of those letters is linked together. I'll update the description

Comment: Please, update your question and clearly indicate these outputs. Don't write them in the comments.

Comment: Updated, I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: This sounds like a common topic, under a different name. Have you considered using a graph library like networkX? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectivity_(graph_theory)

Comment: Lol. You're actually creating a graph with edge lists and looking for depth-first search from a given node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple graph traversal will do it:

Changed your code a bit to use a `set` and apply a [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search):

```py
class MultiLink:
    def __init__(self):
        self.map = {}

    def get(self, md5: str) -> set:
        result = set([])
        def DFS(key: str) -> None:
            for match in self.map[key]:
                if match not in result and match != md5:
                    result.add(match)
                    DFS(match)
        DFS(md5)
        return result

    def link(self, first: str, second: str) -> None:
        if first in self.map:
            self.map[first].add(second)
        else:
            self.map[first] = set([second])

        if second in self.map:
            self.map[second].add(first)
        else:
            self.map[second] = set([first])
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was searching for, thank you. I had read up on graphs at first, but I had never heard of DFS, so I probably would've never figured it out by myself.

Comment: Depending how large your link is you might run into recursive errors. You can also implement DFS as an iterative algorithm using a stack data structure rather than using the call stack.